# Lightning Input Field lenght restriction

Tags: lightning-aura-components, lightning

i cant figure out, how to restrict length of `<lightning:inputField>`.
Something like in HTML `<input type="text" name="usrname" maxlength="10">`.

Is it possible to do with some attribute or there must by some sort of code, in that case, what code? :)

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use onChange event to check lenght of the value of this inputfield and if it is bigger than max lenght change value of the Input field to one beforelast action and show some validation message